# Json with a strange name field cannot be parsed

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have this JSON container that has a strange field called "48x48" for a photoUrl.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
(...)
dynamic issuesJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseIssues.Content);
foreach (dynamic issue in issuesJson.issues){
      Console.WriteLine(issue.name); //works properly
      Console.WriteLine(issue.48x48); //error -> expected;
}
```

For some reason Visual Studio doesn't accept the access to this runtime field of this dynamic object. How can I work around this problem?
Note: I cannot change the field name.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For some reason Visual Studio doesn't accept the access to this runtime field of this dynamic object.

Well what you've provided is simply not valid C#. An identifier can't start with a digit. That's still enforced even when you're trying to resolve a member of `dynamic`.

We don't know what type you're using for `issues`, but basically you'll need to handle it as a key/value map which you can access by string. Quite how you do that will depend on the implementation of `issue`. It doesn't look like Json.NET guarantees anything there - you *may* be able to cast it to `JObject`, for example:

```
foreach (JObject issue in issuesJson.issues) {
    Console.WriteLine(issue["48x48"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Field names **cannot** start with a number. Sorry, no way around it.

You'll have to consult the documentation of your deserializer to see how it takes care of cases like that. It *may* be as simple as renaming the field "_48x48".

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: actually, based on your code, you probably don't have a class representing this JSON object; I'm leaving my answer anyway, in case it helps someone else.

---

As others have mentioned, a C# identifier can't start with a digit. You just need to rename `48x48` to a valid name in your class, and map it to the actual JSON name using the `[JsonProperty]` attribute:

```
[JsonProperty("48x48")]
public string _48x48 { get; set; }
```

Comment: That's assuming the OP actually has a class representing the type - that may well not be the case.

Comment: @JonSkeet, good point; actually, it's probably not the case, given the OP's code...